# Apache .htaccess REQUEST_FILENAME not limited to 257 chars

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, filenames, rules

I run my API trough Apache (2.4.46) using .htaccess-rewriting to provide clean URLs.
Apache has limit of 257 char for filename in URL.

.htacces looks like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^api/name/v([0-99]*)/sub/([0-9a-zA-Z+.,-_]*)/?$ api/name/v$1/sub/?item=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^api/name/v([0-99]*)/sub/([0-9a-zA-Z+.,-_]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z+.,-_]*)/?$ api/name/v$1/sub/?field=$2&item=$3 [L]
```

The 1st rule will limit to 257 chars for items: `api/name/v1/sub/item1,item2,item3,item4,...`
The 2nd rule will not limit to 257 chars for items: `api/name/v1/sub/some_field/item1,item2,item3,item4,...`

I probably use the 2nd-not-recognized-257-char-option to put more items in the URL but I want to rely on the Apache standard to be safe.

**Can anyone figure out why first rewrite rule fits the limit and second not?**

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your efforts in your question. Could you please do mention samples or URLs for which rule is working and for which rules are NOT working? That will give us better understanding of question, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 as written above the URLs are `https://example.org/api/name/v1/sub/item1,item2,item3,item4,...` for example that run into 257 char limit. And `https://example.org/api/name/v1/sub/some_field/item1,item2,item3,item4,...` for example that has NO 257 char limit for item-string

Comment: "As written here Apache has a limit" - the linked question makes no reference to a limit as you seem to imply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This character limit on the URL path segment is actually a limit of the underlying filesystem and doesn't really have anything to do with the directives in `.htaccess`.

It has everything to do with the URLs you are requesting. And when Apache maps the requested URL to the filesystem (which occurs *before* `.htaccess` is processed) then the error is generated.

> The 1st rule will limit to 257 chars for items: `api/name/v1/sub/item1,item2,item3,item4,...`
> The 2nd rule will not limit to 257 chars for items: `api/name/v1/sub/some_field/item1,item2,item3,item4,...`

As noted above, the limit is on the URL - as it maps to the filesystem, not the *rule*.

The reason why the first URL triggers this error is because `/api/name/v1/sub` is a physical directory on the filesystem and `item1,item2,item3,item4,...` is mapped to the filesystem path - which fails.

However, the second URL does not trigger this error, because `some_field` is mapped to the filesystem instead and assuming this is not another subdirectory then `item1,item2,item3,item4,...` becomes additional pathname information (path-info) - it's not mapped to the filesystem, so no error.

To workaround this filesystem limitation you can move the directives to the server config (or VirtualHost) context - which are processed *before* the request is mapped to the filesystem.

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> ^api/name/v([0-99]*)/sub/([0-9a-zA-Z+.,-_]*)/?$
> ```

There's a couple of "errors" in your regex:

- `[0-99]*` - The second `9` is superfluous and is the same as `[0-9]*`. But do you really want to allow an *empty* version string? This should probably be `\d+`.
- `[0-9a-zA-Z+.,-_]` - The unescaped hyphen in the second to last character in the character class creates a *range* so is probably matching more characters than you are expecting, including `/`, `:`, `;` etc. To match just a literal hyphen, you either need to backslash escape it (`\-`) or include it at the start or end of the character class, ie. `[0-9a-zA-Z+.,_-]`, which is the same as `[\w+.,-]`.

> `api/name/v$1/sub/?item=$2`

You aren't actually rewriting directly to a valid end-point. The target URL still requires additional processing - which is not clear from this directive alone. It looks like you are probably relying on the `DirectoryIndex` (eg. `index.php` or `index.html` etc.), so the actual target is more like `api/name/v$1/sub/index.php?item=$2` - it is this that should be used in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* string.

> using .htaccess-rewriting to provide clean URLs

The other niggly thought here is why bother? (Are they really "cleaner"?) These are massively long URLs anyway that are only consumed by an API (a machine). Rewriting these URLs does not really serve any purpose IMO. (?)

Comment: Thanks @MrWhite for the detailed answer! I've seen about the option to put the rule into Vhost config. But this does not fit for my project - due I want to have the API-code outside the docker container that powers PHP itself.